# SAS Invalid data for csv

Tags: sas

Im quite new to SAS and after many attempts Im still wondering how could import my csv file into SAS accurately.

Here's my data

```
color, Description, price
"Black, blue, grey", "Pipe, 16" inch wide, PVC", 20.27
```

Here's my sas code

```
PROC IMPORT datafile='/home/..data.csv'
            out=data dbms=csv replace; 
            getnames=yes;
            guessingrows = max;
RUN;
```

Here's what SAS reads:

```
Color                 Description      Price 
Black, blue, grey     "Pipe             .
```

I suspect SAS treat "Pipe under description instead of Pipe, 16" inch wide, PVC. What could I do so that SAS can read the whole line?

Comment: i tried using DATA ...;  FORMAT ..;  RUN; as well but it didnt manage to generate output as it says the data type for price is invalid,  i guess its the same problem as above. I appreciate any guidance. Thank you

Comment: Post on communities.sas.com for faster response for this question.

Comment: You have an unmatched quotation mark. "Pipe, 16" inch wide, PVC" cannot be parsed as expected. New columns will be made for `16" inch wide` and `PVC"`. If you open it in Excel you will see how it adds new columns as well. You can brute-force solve this by adding extra temporary columns and making a bunch of rules to account for these things, but the best solution is to get the file in another delimited format, such as tab or pipe.

Comment: Who created the file? Can you have them create a version that can be parsed?

Comment: Thank you. @tom its actually a dataset sent to me and I have to check with them

Answer (score 2):

The csv data is invalid.

The 'desired' double quoted value `Pipe, 16" inch wide, PVC` contains both a double-quote (`"`) and the value separator (`,`).   Some CSV readers will parse correctly if the `16"` has an escaped `"` as `16""`.  However, SAS IMPORT appears to be **not** one of those.

Can you get the data with an alternate field delimiter such as `|` or `~`?

Comment: just curious whether "FOMAT color$:17. description$:25. price$:5.;" would help?

Comment: For arbitrary data values you might request data in a fixed field layout, so you know precisely what columns belong to which variable.  If you can get data with two spaces between fields and no field contains two spaces the `&` feature of list input might work.  Read the docs for `INPUT Statement, List`

Comment: Thank you Richard. Just curious whether there is ways to solve it within SAS alone? Would using data step and replacing " with other value such as * then read the sas file again feasible?

Comment: No.  Instead, your code would have to process the line with extra logic, such as inputting color from front of line and then price working backward from end of line and presuming description is what is left over.  If the data provider can not properly delimit the values you have to accept that good logic will be subverted by bad data.